# MyGica S2870 HDTV Stick: how to configure it?

Tags: compatibility, hdtv

Running on ubuntu 14.04 LTS here. Not sure what else to add.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? (other than going back to the store for something else, if possible)

After trying a "sudo lsusb" DiBcom turned in the list. Thing is, I have little clue on how to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect and why isn't it working?

Comment: Doesn't even see it. I did some extra research. It's not compatible. Only the S870 HDTV stick works on linux. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Issue closed: apparently it can't be done. There are no drivers for that device. Only the S870 HDTV works for linux. Thanks.